# Install and start programming Ruby on Rails on Mac?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to try ruby on rails on mac. I want to install ruby on rails, tried to find some guide for installation, and I get this:

[ruby on rails official website??](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/getting-started/installation/mac)

It does not have a clear, I mean, well documentation for beginner to follow the steps? Or, thats all for the installation? How to start the webserver, where to store ruby files etc, ... how do I get started???

Any advise, or links or tutorials for a total ruby beginner to get started?

Answer (score 0):

This is their official guide:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

You need to install xcode first though to avoid some errors. This is because some of the headers in the default ruby install on macs is incomplete without it.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need GCC, which used to be with XCode only but over at ye olde [GitHub, it's been packaged as a standalone](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer). Next up you can follow either [this tutorial by Katz](http://www.blog.bridgeutopiaweb.com/post/how-to-install-rvm-and-rails-3-on-snow-leopard/) or [Dan Benjamin's](http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-ruby-rubygems-and-rails-on-snow-leopard/)  guide on HiveLogic.

Keep in mind the state of the art in Ruby and Rails is fast moving so the guides might not take you all the way there. The most crucial parts are getting RVM installed properly and working and getting everything on the right version. It's not too tricky to work through, and there's probably no undocumented issues in the process now.